# how to cool down raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, temperature, cpu, overclocking

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 running 24h/24h at 100%: it is costantly at 70°C..

I'd like to know if there are simple and cheap solutions to cool it down.

Comment: they sell small fans powered via the gpio like this one https://www.adafruit.com/product/3368

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two easy solutions:

- A fan powered by the GPIOs. Just take an old computer fan running at 12 Volts and plug it on the GND and 5V output of the pi. It will run slower than on 12 Volts of course, but fast enough to cool.
- You can also buy cooling rips. You can get them specifically made for the pi or you can also use transistor cooling rips. You can get them for 35c.

You can combine both of course.

Comment: Running a 12V fan at 5V is actually not sound advice as it might not spin properly or worse: seems to work now but fails after collecting dust for a year.

Comment: @Ghanima Haven't heard of that before. But those Fans are so cheap, they can be changed easily.

Comment: Most 12V fans will fail to start spinning on 5V.  The stall current they draw in that case is much greater than the normal current (which for big PC fans is already signficant in terms of a small Rpi power supply).

Comment: @ChrisH I never had problems with 12V fans connected to the RPi. And I also had mine running 24/7. I even had two of them connected to the RPi.

Comment: @NoahKrasser fair enough. I've had plenty that would keep going indefinitely once started but not start below about 1/2 the rated voltage

Answer (score 2):

That temperature is the peak temperature at which Raspberry Pi can operate safely. It is recommended to use a heatsink with a fan that can be plugged into one of the pins in Raspberry Pi, as shown below

[image]

It will help it to cool down the temperature significantly. You can buy one of them at amazon or any other online store. But if you need any other more cool option, you should check out this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7cc4eLAOMk&t=321s

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a [5v fan](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/axial-fans/1118331/) connected to 5v and ground, and some good quality [heat sinks](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/heatsinks/8679039/).

Answer (score 1):

Heat sinks designed for the chips work well for keeping the pi from heating up quite as fast.

Answer (score 0):

I, personally use a air conditioner. I put it on medium while I'm doing basic stuff and put it on max when I'm doing something CPU/Other thing intensive stuff.

Actually, you can find one on eBay pretty cheap! When I'm not using the Raspberry Pi, I bring it out from under my desk and put it to low.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).